# Is there a better way/pattern to tag the content of a POJO in different "sizes"?

Tags: java, multithreading

Well I'm playing a little bit with threads in Java and ended up with a "try" to tag the "size" of the objects instantiated. Lets say I want to open the evaluation of the sizes to the implementer and make the process using threads as much transparent as possible of the objects to process.

I want to improve if its possible the following class sizes markers. I tried with @annotations but I can't force the implementations to retrieve the size based on the object content(that's why the interface with the method `ExecutionerSize getSize()`)

As parents I have this class and interface:

```
public class WorkerEntity implements ExecutionerSize{
    @Override
    public ExecutionerSize getSize() {
        "implementation of the evaluation to get the size..."
    }
}

public interface ExecutionerSize {
    ExecutionerSize getSize();
}
```

As children of the previous class and interface:

```
public interface Large extends ExecutionerSize{
}
public interface Medium extends ExecutionerSize{
}
public interface Small extends ExecutionerSize{
}

public class WorkerEntityLarge extends WorkerEntity implements Large {
}
public class WorkerEntityMedium extends WorkerEntity implements Medium{
}
public class WorkerEntitySmall extends WorkerEntity implements Small{
}
```

And here its my "problem" this is the only way I accomplish to success the split of the `List<ExecutionerSize>`

```
private List<WorkerEntity>[] splitListIntoSizes(List<ExecutionerSize> objectsToProcess) {
        List<Small> smallList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Medium> mediumList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Large> largeList = new ArrayList<>();
        objectsToProcess.forEach(object -> {
            ExecutionerSize objectSized = object.getSize();
            if (objectSized instanceof WorkerEntitySmall) {
                smallList.add((WorkerEntitySmall) objectSized);
            } else if (objectSized instanceof WorkerEntityMedium) {
                mediumList.add((WorkerEntityMedium) objectSized);
            } else {
                largeList.add((WorkerEntityLarge) objectSized);
            }
        });
        return new List[]{smallList, mediumList, largeList};
 }
```

For more code details here is the github repo: https://github.com/RJansenGomez/ThreadsPoc

Comment: That's the only way (with `instanceof`) available with your design.

Comment: Hints of other designs that would achieve the same in a more clearer/shorter way?

Comment: It is very awkward that the size of an `ExecutionerSize` is itself an `ExecutionerSize`. You could probably represent it with an `enum` type.

Comment: Yup, I did that other approach time ago but was looking for a more "clean" side in the processing of the data, like "more transparent" to avoid the bunch of if/else depending of the value from the enum and also maybe for further implementations depending on the size of the object to implement the processor